# analyze / model the difference between experiment and control group

Tags: anova, experiment-design, cart

In an experiment with experiment vs control groups, how to train model to explain the different results between experiment and control group (ie, has treatment vs no treatment)?

Eg, customer engagement experiment with

```
experiment group: gets coupon
control group: no coupon
```

we have

```
Target Y = 1/0 (made purchase or not)
Features: x1, x2, ... (age, gender, ...) 
          and has_coupon (binary, or equivalently grp = exp vs ctrl)
```

want to explain the difference in the purchase rate: y_exp - y_ctrl. Eg,

> which features correlated w/ this difference?
> Can I isolate subgroup where y_exp - y_ctrl is bigger or smaller than overall difference?

I was thinking of run model
Y ~ x1,x2,..., has_coupon
But, if the result shows x1 is has biggest correlation with Y, it doesn’t explain y_exp - y_ctrl (unless u also see x1 is biased in experiment and control groups)

My feeling is I need to model
Y ~ interaction of has_coupon * x1,x2,...
but would like some help / experience shared about this.

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about what you mean by $x_1$, $x_2$, and 'Group'? I think you're saying that you have several different customers, some of whom receive a treatment of a coupon, and some of whom receive the control of no coupon. You want to find the effect of being given a coupon on a customer's purchase rate. Is this correct?

Comment: If so, you simply need to fit the model $y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i$, where $y_i = 1$ if customer $i$ made a purchase and 0 otherwise, and $x_i  = 1$ if customer $i$ received a coupon and 0 otherwise. Then, $\alpha$ is the 'base' purchase rate for those customers who didn't receive coupons (for whom $x_i = 0$), and $\beta$ is the effect of the coupon (i.e. the average change in $y_i$ associated with moving from $x_i = 0$, no coupon, to $x_i = 1$, coupon). You might be better off using a logistic regression model,  however. Anyhow, please clarify what effect you want to identify.